# "Rule's" for reducilibility depending on degree of a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I want to make sure I have the following information correct. Here is what I understand regarding the reducibility of polynomials of different degrees on $F[x]$, $F$ a field.

Let $f(x) \in F[x]$

**f has degree 0 or 1**

Say $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$

Then $deg(f) = deg(g) + deg(h)$

So one of $g$ and $h$ must have degree 0. And hence it will be a unit as $F$ a field. So polynomials of degree 0 or 1 are irreducible.

**f has degree 2 or 3**

$f$ is reducible if and only if $f$ has a root $\Longleftrightarrow f$ is irreducible if and only if $f$ doesn't have a root.

**f has degree 4 or greater**

$f$ has a root $\implies f$ is reducible.

But the converse is not true, $f$ can be reducible but not have a root.

1. Are all my assumptions correct?
2. And can I say anything specifically about irreducibility when dealing with polynomials of degree 4 or greater? I.e. Does "$f$ has a root $\implies f$ is reducible" imply "$f$ has is irreducible $\implies f$ doesn't have a root"? It seems like that is a reasonable statement.

Comment: Everything looks good to me. Of course, all of these statements apply over a field, not in general. The last statement you made is valid as well; Otherwise you can factor the linear factor.

Comment: Polynomials of degree $0$ are units, not irreducible. The other things are correct.

Comment: For degree higher than three, other methods are required to prove something is irreducible, for example Eisenstein's criterion.